# Stack Overflow certificate

Tags: support, questions

Does Stack Overflow provide any user certificate for reputation, or active participation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Absolutely!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)

[image]

You might have meant hard-copy, though. If so, no.

Comment: Unless you count T-shirts, but since those are now available to the general public...

Comment: this only looks like a badge / signature... not a Certificate...

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is visible online in forms of Flair (see Michael's answer) as well as your profile. If you want to use it in your Resume, just give them a link to your profile.

Comment: try this link... how can one say who is this.... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/27414/status-declined

Comment: @binil: Well, StackOverflow does not know real identity of its users. You can change your nickname (or "About me") to indicate who you really are. It would be hard not to believe your link if you can actually change your profile (let us forgot profile hijacking for a moment).